# unable to open trace file

Tags: android

I want to test the performance of my app . I have started it with simple application and try to put traceview but its suddenly fail on my android phone with force to close. Please guide me how can i set my code propley for simple android app to get hands dirt with Trace view

Here is the code 
package test.check;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;

public class tracev extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Debug.startMethodTracing("traceview");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Debug.stopMethodTracing();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="test.check"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".tracev"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but its not working . I think its becasue of this line in the logcat but i am not sure how  to deal with it

```
05-20 23:39:43.913: ERROR/dalvikvm(11673): Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/traceview.trace': Permission denied
```

Logcat

```
05-20 23:39:43.903: DEBUG/dalvikvm(11673): +++ active profiler count now 1
05-20 23:39:43.913: INFO/dalvikvm(11673): TRACE STARTED: '/sdcard/traceview.trace' 8192KB
05-20 23:39:43.913: ERROR/dalvikvm(11673): Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/traceview.trace': Permission denied
05-20 23:39:43.913: DEBUG/dalvikvm(11673): +++ active profiler count now 0
05-20 23:39:43.913: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(11673): Shutting down VM
05-20 23:39:43.913: WARN/dalvikvm(11673): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
05-20 23:39:43.913: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.check/test.check.tracev}: java.lang.RuntimeException: file open failed
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file open failed
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracing(Native Method)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracing(VMDebug.java:156)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing(Debug.java:443)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing(Debug.java:391)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at test.check.tracev.onCreate(tracev.java:12)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
05-20 23:39:43.983: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11673):     ... 11 more
05-20 23:39:44.013: INFO/Process(94): Sending signal. PID: 11673 SIG: 3
05-20 23:39:44.013: INFO/dalvikvm(11673): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-20 23:39:44.023: INFO/dalvikvm(11673): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-20 23:39:51.213: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(94): pokeWakelock(15000)
05-20 23:39:51.213: INFO/HtcLockScreen(94): Press Menu key to unlock screen
```

I am wondering about one point there is nothing in the sdcard and in front of it there is no device selected . May be it can be the cause of error , here is the picture 
[image]

Comment: can you show us your manifest?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? and are you using the emulator? if so, did you create a virtual SD card for it ?

Comment: @ MByD I have added Manifest file

Comment: @Luis Miguel Serrano its <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" /> and i am direclty running on my android phone

Comment: please check i have added one more picture about which i am wondering

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is an emulator, make sure that emulator has an SDCard attached to it.

Also, best practice is to use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

Try putting the permissions line right under the `uses-sdk` line.

Use a different file name than `traceview` to make sure no other app has lock on it.

Your SD Card appears to be empty. Have you been able to access it before?  It may be corrupt.

Comment: i am directly running on my android phone

Comment: Edited with another suggestion.

Comment: tried "Try putting the permissions line right under the uses-sdk line" but not working :(

Comment: please check i have added one more picture related to question . in front of sd card there is no device selected and there is nothing in the sdcard as well . If it is the problem please let me knw how i can select the device

Comment: tried "Use a different file name than traceview to make sure no other app has lock on it" but no hope

Comment: Haphazard you are my hero . you know what i remove my android phone and replug it then i got all the things in that sd card . Really thanks alot . now last thing now i am getting myapp.trace in sdcard how can i open it

Comment: You could mount your phone's SDCard and try to open it with NotePad or TextPad.

Comment: Thats worked very well but how i can see the graph from this file in windows

Comment: take a look a-yonder http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-performance-profiling-and-how.html

Comment: Thanks a lot  Haphazard . I have learned a lot from you . I will now try to open this file according to your  suggested link .

Comment: Also, make sure you have USB storage off.

Answer (score 11):

On Marshmallow (Android-Version 6, API Level 23) just having the "write" permission in manifest isn't enough. You have to ask for that [permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), or you can go to system preferences and give the storage permission to your app.

Comment: this was my issue, found my app in the app list and enabled the storage permissions on my device.

Answer (score 6):

Using TraceView requires 2 permissions:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

Comment: Since SD storage is enabled by default with new Android Studion, this fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Under Android Virtual Device Manager, Select and Edit your emulator. 
Give some value under SD Card option:

Size : 100 MB

This should work for you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I found is to use [Context.getFileDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) as storage location. This has the following advantages over [Context.getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

- it also works when there is no SD-card (in your device or emulator)
- it does not need any additional permissions

Example-code to start method-tracing:

```
final File methodTracingFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "AppStart.trace");
Log.d(TAG, "methodTracingPath=" + methodTracingFile.getPath());
Debug.startMethodTracing(methodTracingFile.getPath());
```

Note: it's a good idea to log the `methodTracingPath` to see where the file will be stored.
Example: `/data/data/com.YOUR_PACKAGE.debug/files/AppStart.trace`

To copy the file from your Emulator to your PC, you can use the *File Explorer* in the *Android Device Monitor* (see [Working with an emulator or device's file system](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html#emulator))
[image]

1. select the trace file
2. click the *Pull a file from device* button to copy it to your local PC

Finally you can just drag&drop the trace file to Android Studio to see the [method trace-view](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html).

Answer (score 1):

My trace file have **no data when**

- `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` is inside `onDestroy()` method of Activity
- Missing request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

I can not find trace file when

- For some device trace file in inside `File Exployer -> sdcard -> Android -> data -> your_app -> files` but some device it is inside `File Exployer -> sdcard` and some device it is inside `File Exployer -> data`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while debugging on my physical device and found this question. I fixed it by:

1. Go into the Developer Options setting on the phone (how to enable: [How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4) )
2. Click Select debug app item.
3. Select your application from the list.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers fix my problem. I end up have to

1. Root my phone
2. Change the call to

   Debug.startMethodTracing("/data/local/startup");

where I touch the file before run and chmod to 777.