# How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4

Tags: android

In settings on my [Nexus 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4) device there isn't any "USB debugging options" item. How do I find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4?

Comment: go to your settings , about device/phone. then tap 7 to 8 times on the build number list item. You will be declared as a developer

Comment: How do you use it though

Comment: I would note that a troubleshooting step (I vaguely recall being recommended by google over the phone) was to turn off debugging mode! –

Answer (score 327, accepted):

**Solution**

To see the option for USB debugging mode in Nexus 4 or Android 4.2 or higher OS, do the following:

- Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the
  Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
- Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
- At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number”
  seven times.

  - Make sure you tap seven times. If you see
    a “Not need, you are already a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have
    done it correctly.

Done! By tapping on “Build number” seven times, you have unlocked USB debugging mode on Android 4.2 and higher. You can now enable/disable it whenever you desire by going to 
“Settings” -> “Developer Options” -> “Debugging” ->” USB debugging”.

**CONCLUSION**

That was easy. The best part is you only have to do the tap-build-number-seven-times once. After you do it once, USB debugging has been unlocked and you can enable or disable at your leisure. Please restart after done these steps.

**Additional information**

[**Setting up a Device for Development**](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) native documentation of Google Android developer site

**Update: Google Pixel 3**

If you need to facilitate a connection between your device and a computer with the Android SDK (software development kit), view this info.

1. From a Home screen, swipe up to display all apps.
2. Navigate: **Settings**  > **System**  > **Advanced**.
3. **Developer options** .
        If Developer options isn't available, navigate: **Settings** > **About phone** then tap **Build number** 7 times. Tap the **Back icon**  to Settings then select System > Advanced > Developer options.
4. Ensure that the Developer options switch (upper-right) is turned on .
5. Tap **USB debugging** to turn on  or off .
6. If prompted with 'Allow USB debugging?', tap **OK** to confirm.

Doc by Verizon: [Original source](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-219978/)

Comment: Restarting is not necessary, at least not in versions >= 4.2.

Comment: On some devices, it might be Settings -> About -> Software Information -> More -> Build Number

Comment: Note. I have Android 4.3 and I need restarting. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: no one explains what should happen after the "USB Debugging" is enabled?! I enabled it and connected the device via USB to my machine.... now what? How I do debug?

Comment: At first I tried up up down down left right left right b a select start. Didn't work. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: In some older devices, it can be achieved by : Settings > Applications > Development > check "USB debugging".

Comment: I have not found it on my Pixel 3 running Android 10.

Answer (score 7):

Looking for About Phone in Settings. And scroll down till you see Build number. Tap here till you see Toast message tell you have just enable developer mode.

Back to settings, you can see options: "Developer options"

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1 :** Go to Settings >> About Phone >> scroll to the bottom >> tap Build number seven times; this message will appear “You are now 3 steps away from being a developer.”

**Step 2 :** Now go to Settings >> Developer Options >> Check USB Debugging

this is great article will help you to enable this mode on your phone

[Enable USB Debugging Mode on Android](http://www.idadtech.com/enable-disable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android)

Comment: @ChrisBrown your recovery-tool spam is not welcome here

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Settings > About Phone > scroll to the bottom > tap Build number seven (7) times. You'll get a short pop-up in the lower area of your display saying that you're now a developer. 2. Go back and now access the Developer options menu, check 'USB debugging' and click OK on the prompt. This Guide Might Help You : [How to Enable USB Debugging in Android Phones](http://idroidhorizon.blogspot.com/2014/06/How-to-Enable-USB-Debugging-in-Android.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you enabled `debugging mode` on your phone and `adb devices` is not listing your device, it seems there is a problem with phone driver. You might not install the usb-driver of your phone or driver might be installed with problems (in windows check in system --> device manager).

In my case, I had the same problem with My HTC android usb device which installing drivers again, fixed my problems.

Answer (score -1):

Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the Menu button while on your home screen and tapping settings icon then scroll down to developer options and tap it then you will see on the top right a on off switch select on and then tap ok, thats it you all done.

Comment: by the way its not for nexus one uts for android 4.2.2  ver. and i just switch it on in a android tablet. good luck guys.