# Any idea why adb does not recognize my nexus 4 on mac

Tags: android, adb, nexus-4

I can't figure out why my nexus 4 is absent from the list of adb devices. I've tried the following

- $ adb kill-server; adb devices
- $ echo 0x18d1 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
  $ adb kill-server; adb devices
- Changed usb computer connection type to PTP instead of MTP
- Restarted the phone etc

Adb is on my path. Nexus 4 shows up when I view System Information.

I've tried asking on xda devs but no luck. Any suggestions on what I can try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try lsusb in your terminal and check your vendor id is correct 18d1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very weird, I switched to a cheap chinese made cable and now adb sees my device.

Comment: This was it for me as well, the cable would charge but not connect with adb. Thanks!

Comment: I spent an hour searching for the issue when I found this. I tried another cable and now it works! Especially weird because the other cable worked with a Nexus 7

Comment: Sometimes it is the simple things! I tried all sorts of things and it was a cable issue!

Answer (score 11):

I was only getting a blank result when I run: ./adb devices
nothing would show up.

Here's the fix:

1. SDK (Latest Version)
2. Put developer mode on nexus 4 ( About Phone > Build Number > tap 7 times to enter Dev Mode)
3. A new menu will pop up  {} Developer Options -
4. Make sure you check under Developer options:

   - USB Debugging : Debug mode when USB is connected
   - Verify apps over USB : Check apps installed via ADB/ADT for Harmful behavior

This worked for me, no try: ./adb devices 
Then my serial number of my Nexus 4 was displayed.

Good luck.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first enable "Developer" mode on the device before trying "adb devices" option. Here is the topic that explains how.

[How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4).

This worked for me.

Comment: That doesn't work as well. It shows "USB debugging connected" on the nexus but not under adb devices

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your device with the developer option enabled, and the USB debugging enabled, it should prompt you about remote debugging. If that prompt doesn't happen, it means the device is not seen by the Mac or ADB.

In my experience on MacOS X, you have to try different USB ports and sometimes disconnect all other USB devices (including the keyboard...).

Once the device finally pops up in your terminal, you can reconnect the devices if required.

Comment: Yep, changing the USB port seems to help here as well

Answer (score 0):

Its because that you didnt update your SDK

you need to update you SDK to the latest one

i.e API level 17

your Nexes 4 OS version is 4.2 so you need to update your android sdk to API leve 17 4.2 to detect it.

Comment: I'm on 17 https://www.evernote.com/shard/s307/sh/c3e6f4a8-7082-436f-84f2-11220781b7c2/094e0538c36d05ba821928ab92f0e92e

Comment: me and few of my colleagues faced the same problem. when updating to the latest SDK we resolved it. I don't know why not for you?