# Visual Studio 2010 can't see nexus 4

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, monogame

So I made a game in XNA, ported it to MonoGame Android, when the you click debug, the select device window appears, my phone is connected to the PC, usb debugging enabled, but the phone doesn't appear that list. Any ideas what is going on? If I make an emulator, that emulator shows up.

Comment: Try this [link](http://%20http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4)

Comment: This isn't what my question is asking, usb debugging is already on, like I said.

Comment: Then try this [other](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992345)

Comment: "Windows was unable to install your nexus 4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a driver provided by pdanet, worked. :/

http://pdanet.co/

Comment: Provide a link to the driver for other people's benefit and accept your own answer.