# android 4.2.2: cannot see device through usb

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, windows-7-x64, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using Samsung Galaxy nexus for several years. I always update my kernel. Now, it is 4.2.2. I haven't developed on my phone for a year. Recently I pickup my old project and found out my computer (Windows 7 64bit) cannot connect to my phone for debugging.

My computer can connect my phone for files transfer, but not for debugging through eclipse. Adb.exe cannot list the device either. I do some searchings on the web and found out I am not alone. However, I still got no solution. I hope someone could help.

Or anyone can give me a way to read the error/information log like logcat does. Thank you very much!

Regards,

Antony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone is not enabled for debug, try this (from [How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4)):

1. Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the
   Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
2. Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
3. At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number”
   seven times.
4. Make sure you tap seven times. If you see a “Not need,
   you are already a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have
   done it correctly.

Comment: Good1 .I hope it will useful

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did the 7 tap on "Build number" and the message did appear. However, I still cannot connect my phone through adb.exe. I could transfer files to the phone when connected usb, but no device find in using adb.exe. I use adb devices -l. Nothing appear after "List of device attached".

Comment: After enabling "Developer options" by following the steps above, which is the configuration you can see when you enter "Developer options" in "Settings"?  Which checks are enabled?