# Debugging in Eclipse/Emulator not hitting breakpoints

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have configured a VD through Eclipse and it starts up fine. If I press F11 from one of my .java files in my application project, it starts up a new instance of the emulator and installs the app on it. However it does not open the app and if I manually open it and click on action buttons, it plainly is not linked up to the IDE for debugging as no break points get hit.

Other times when the emulator is open, F11 does the job of re-installing the app (after I manually uninstall it from the emulator), but again it does not attach as a debugger, just installs the app so I can run it.

Is there something basic I am doing wrong so that step-through debugging is not working?

Comment: write android.os.Debug.waitfordebugger(); in your oncreate

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse having option **Skip All Breakpoints**,

it might be possible you enable this option so you need to disable Skip All Breakpoints,

Option will appear when you will right click on project and trying to run it.

[image]

You can also do it by UI of eclipse , figure out this images.  there are a option, if you toggle this button option it will behave disabe/ enable

Comment: Thanks, this option is not ticked though unfortunately so it is not that.

Comment: go through these links:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDebugging/article.html

Comment: or add add `android:debuggable="true"` to the  <application> element Manifest file.

Comment: After some tinkering around, I have noticed that if I fire up the emulator, open the App, then go into DDNS view, find the app on the left and highlight it, then click the debug icon to mark it as debugging, then switch to debug view, and THEN press the button in the app, the breakpoints get hit. So I have a workaround, but it is quite time consuming. Is there not an easy way to have it debug your app with one button click like you can in Visual Studio with C#?

Comment: If you Run your Application `Debug as Android Application` it will enable debug mode by default, i think you are running your application as debug mode or not. or Run your application by clicking on debug icon on eclipse tool bar,