# rajwali live wallpaper stops working

Tags: android, rajawali

After installing on Nexus 7 RajawaliWallpaperTemplate from [RajawaliWallpaperTemplate](https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliWallpaperTemplate)

it stops working after I rotate the device several time.
Says: Unfortunately ,Rajawali Wallpaper Template has stopped.

I can't fix, are there any solutions ? 
Thank you.

Comment: What errors are shown in the LogCat?

Comment: there aren't show any errors, I can set the wallpaper, it works but If I rotate the device a few times soon or later it stops working.

Comment: you need to provide `Logcat` output as well as stacktrace for answer

Comment: Nick the errors are output to a log that is readable by LogCat on your PC.  Are you running logcat, or DDMS (includes a logcat view) either stand alone or in Eclispe/Android studio?  If you have your device connected when it and app force closes your will have log messages produced.  If you don't understand what this means you need to look into debugging Android apps.  Look here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html.  Also [search stackoverflow for DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+[ddms])

Comment: If you are really new to development (we all start somewhere) you might also find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4

Comment: thanks for the reply :)  I don't know if I did something wrong, (I know the basics step for android) but it shows only :

Comment: 10-08 22:49:38 - RajawaliWallpaperTemplate] Installing RajawaliWallpaperTemplate.apk...
[2014-10-08 22:49:49 - RajawaliWallpaperTemplate] Success!
[2014-10-08 22:49:50 - RajawaliWallpaperTemplate] Starting activity com.mydomain.wallpaper.mywallpaper.Preview on device 015d15b4fb0bf40b
[2014-10-08 22:49:54 - RajawaliWallpaperTemplate] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mydomain.wallpaper.mywallpaper/.Preview }

Comment: Than when I click setWallpaper everythings works, and when I rotate the screen a few times it gives me Unfortunately wallpaper has stopped... I have checked the debuggin in my nexus 7.