# Getting internal system configurations RAM info in Android?

Tags: android

Im a beginner in Android Development and please excuse if question is not relevant or there are some alternate ways,i have developed an application wherein which i get/retrieve smartphone infos like :

ModelNumber

RAM size

Resolution

Kernel version

But is there any way to find the core features like RAM versions (indepth infos ,as we use `msconfig` in windows O.S to find system infos) ,also i have tried [secret codes](http://www.kompyooter.com/?qa=58/how-to-find-ram-version-in-android-smartphone) `*#*#3264#*#*` but no help

Thanks ,please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you proceed to Android development,

1. you need to install Android SDK Tools + IDE: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
2. enable debug mode on the phone:
   [How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4)
3. then through the console ( windows_button + R and type "cmd")

   - Go to the Android Tools bin folder
   - plug phone to usb
   - and run the command 
     `adb.exe shell`

In this console will be available:

- ModelNumber:

  `cat /system/build.prop | grep product`
- Ram size:

  `cat /proc/meminfo`
- Resolution:

  `dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | grep "FB |"`
- Kernel version:

  `cat /proc/version`

Comment: can i retrieve only capacity of the ram ?

Comment: no problem:     cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal |  grep -o "[[:<:]][0-9]*[[:>:]]"         Put it one line. It is in kilobytes.

Comment: thank you @Krinil one more question ,correct me if im wrong..The only thing i can retrieve about RAM is memory ? is there some other infos about RAM which i can get like RAM manufacturer llike that...

Comment: Ordinary Linux x86 kernel has SMBIOS access(for ex.: dmidecode util), but I can't find something like this technology on the ARM platform.

Comment: thank you @Krinil for your time..please do update if you find some new infos about the same.Thank you