# Xamarin IDE sees 4.4.3 but not 4.4.2

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a Samsung S3 running 4.4.3 and I have been using it with Xamrine IDE without issues.  As soon as I connect the USB to my Win 7 laptop the IDE shows the device on the list and I"m able to debug and upload code to it.  It works.

My wife recently bought the same brand and model phone (Samsung S3) but hers runs 4.4.2.  When I connect her phone to the same laptop nothing happens.  IDE doesn't see it although the Win OS recognize it and I"m able to upload files to the phone.

I"m using googles USB driver.  I did a search and I found the following driver from Intel that's [specific for connecting to android.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices).  I applied the driver from Intel but I'm still can't connect to 4.4.2.  I restarted the IDE (but didn't restart the computer) but to no avail.  Again, the only difference that I can tell between my phone and hers is version number - mine is 4.4.3 which works with Xamarin IDE and hers is 4.4.2 which does not.

Anyone have any ideas of what I can do to make 4.4.2 work with Xamarin IDE?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is debugging enabled?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4

Comment: @Jason yea it is.  USB Debugging is checked.

Comment: If the Android sdks "adb devices" does not list the device, XS is not going to see it. Try "adb kill-server" & "adb start-server" and re-list the devices... If nothing, then the phone is not in debug mode, and/or the wrong USB drivers are installed, and/or multiple drivers are installed and Windows is choosing the wrong one. Look at device manager and see if it the showing up and NOT using a USB storage device.