# My Android device is not listed while started selendroid server

Tags: android, selendroid

While starting selendroid server, my physical device could not be loaded. But my virtual device was loaded. I tried reconnecting my device and restarting 'adb' server. but it didn't help. When i use this command, it lists my physical device, not my virtual device.

```
adb devices
```

Error log:

INFO: Executing shell command: C:\Users\siva\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\a
ndroid.bat list avds
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: Nexus_5_API_23_x86-_cust1
  Device: Nexus 5 (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\siva.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
 Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
    Skin: nexus_5
  Sdcard: C:\Users\siva.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd\sdcard.img
Snapshot: yes  -------

Name: nexus_api21
  Device: Nexus 4 (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\siva.android\avd\nexus_api21.avd
  Target: Android 5.0.1 (API level 21)
 Tag/ABI: default/x86_64
    Skin: WXGA800
  Sdcard: 64M

The following Android Virtual Devices could not be loaded:
    Name: Samsung_Galaxy_J5_API_23
    Path: C:\Users\siva.android\avd\Samsung_Galaxy_J5_API_23.avd
   Error: User Samsung Galaxy J5 no longer exists as a device

Oct 03, 2015 8:35:14 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: C:\Users\siva\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platfor
m-tools\adb.exe devices
Oct 03, 2015 8:35:15 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Shell command output
-->
List of devices attached
e87bc24b        device

Help me out...

Answer (score 0):

1. USB debugging enable?

[How to find and turn on USB debugging mode on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4)

2. Select Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers >> Devices. Right click on your physical device >> Properties >> Hardware. After these steps check your device function. Is it ADB Inteface?

http://adbdriver.com/