# How can i run my android application on nexus 5 mobile phone

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.1.2,
Android 6.0 API Level 23,
Mobile Google Nexus 5,
I am trying to debug my application on my mobile phone instead on the emulator. Adb didn't show my nexus 5 in the connected device. Adb says USB device not found.

Although windows explorer shows device is connected.And I have also enabled USB debugging and developer option mode on the nexus 5 mobile.

How can i run my android application on nexus 5 mobile phone.

Please help

Comment: You can look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4

Comment: Have you installed the USB driver?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to begin by going to the SDK Manager. Since we have been using Android Studio so far it is just as easy to navigate to it through the IDE by going to Tools->Android->SDK Manager.

Search for “Google USB Driver”
Then make sure you place a checkmark in “Google USB Driver” and hit the install packages button.

For 32 bit user go to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver”

And for 64 bit user go to:

C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver”

Click on android_'winusb.inf' and install it.

After the installation go to your device.
In setting tap on “Developer options” and place a checkmark in “Stay Awake” and “USB Debugging”.

Now connect your device to your USB port on your computer.
Place a checkmark in the “Always allow from this computer” and hit “OK”. You are now free to open Android Studio and run your app on your local device!

Answer (score 0):

u can download this driver via this link http://adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip

and Enable Developer Options

and Enable "USB Debugging"

Answer (score 0):

1. Download ADB Driver Installer from http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ and open it.
2. Connect your device to your USB port on your computer.
3. When your device appears in the ADB Driver Installer, select it and hit install button.
4. Now you have successfully installed the driver and your mobile will be connected.