# Cant upload my app with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to upload a testing app (just blank page) to my phone.
I can see my phone in the list when I press run and there is no new app in my phone and nothing apears there.

why?
thank you.

Comment: Check logcat for errors. What does it say?

Comment: Verify that you enable USB debugging under Developer options - check this:
https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you app is failing to compile, you will need to check Android Studio for compilation errors. These can be found in the `Messages` view.

To put your app on a device, your test device will need `USB Debugging` enabled on it. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707217/717778) for more information on how to turn it on should you have missed this step.

If the app **is** compiling but isn't starting, ensure that you have the following `intent-filter` within your main activity's definition in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourMainActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This intent filter is how the Android OS works out which activity to launch when the app is freshly opened. Without this filter, no activity will start.

Comment: Please post the `onCreate` method of your main activity @DorEliyahu