# Animation not working in custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

This code is working with no errors but it is not showing any animation in the dialog. Just added the 2 anim files for animation and added dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogTheme);
in the main java file.
also declared in styles.xml file.
but no animation is being shown.
I am new to android.

Main Activity

```
package com.dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//Custom Dialog
public void open(View view)
{
    final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
    Button btnDismiss=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDismiss);
    Button btnOkay=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOkay);
    btnOkay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Dialog     Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogTheme);
    dialog.show();
}


public void close(View view)
{
    finish();
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dialog App"
    android:id="@+id/tvApp"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvApp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dialog"
    android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvApp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:onClick="open"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_right</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

@anim/slide_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

@anim/slide_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"  />
</set>
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Sure??"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvDismiss" />

<Button
    android:text="Okay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnOkay"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvDismiss"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Dismiss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnDismiss"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnOkay"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnOkay" />
<Button
    android:text="Exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDismiss"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnOkay"
    android:onClick="close"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i also tried using dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =R.style.DialogTheme         but i got no result

Comment: I also tried same of your code but it is working fine at my side.

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva Do you think that it is not working for me because I am using an emulator to run it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the interpolator value. Used accelarate interpolator with 5000 duration which is too long for it. Setting the value of duration to 1000 makes the code work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code, the only problem it might have is may be the animations for dialogs are not enabled in your device.

Check if your devices animation settings are set to "No Animations" (Settings → Display → Animation) then the dialogs will not show any animations, you need to turn that on and try if your code works.

Comment: There is no animation option in the display settings. I am using an emulator to run my code. Could that be the problem??

Comment: for some devices you may find it under developer options, by the name of window animations or something.. even in emulators... you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4 post to turn developer options on in any device, if you haven't done that before

Comment: I did find the animation settings but it is  active.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);`

`dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogTheme)` is not work for dialog, because `set style` is just on `init()`, but `dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations()` is after init(), so it's not working.

Sometime, `Instant Run` will ignore this change, so you can try disable `Instant Run`

last try set android:duration = 1000.

Comment: It covers the whole screen now. Even in that, no animations occur

Comment: @MohitTaparia Sometime, `Instant Run` will ignore this change, so you can try disable `Instant Run`

Comment: I did not have Instant Run enabled.

Comment: @MohitTaparia try set `android:duration = 1000`

Comment: Could you tell possible reasons of failure?

Comment: @MohitTaparia sorry actually, i don`t know why ....I guess animation duration too long and some action will interrupt that. if you had some ideal for this magic question can you mention me?. thanks.

Comment: I think the problem was with the interpolator. I used accelarate interpolator with 5000 duration which was too long for it.

Comment: @MohitTaparia It is believable, I hv got it yesterday, thank you.  can i add your fb?

Comment: Sure...     " fb/mohittaparia96"