# Debug.startMethodTracing("xyz") crashes the App

Tags: android, performance

Trying to get a traceview dump for the coldstart of my Application.
I added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and have the 
`Debug.startMethodTracing("xyz")` in the `onCreate` of my Application class.

My app crashes with `Permission denied`

```
02-27 17:48:06.173 3395-3395/: Unable to open trace file '/storage/emulated/legacy/xyz.trace': Permission denied
02-27 17:48:06.174 3395-3395/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application (...): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open trace file '/storage/emulated/legacy/xyz.trace'
```

Edit 1: I am doing this on a real Nexus 6 device running Lollipop

**Solution:**

So probably some library was overriding the write external storage permissions. I added this to the AndroidManifest.xml and it started working

**Emphasis on the tools:node="replace"**

Comment: please check this .  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077953/unable-to-open-trace-file
i hope it's help full for you .

Comment: @SanjayChauhan: I read that thread, none of the solutions solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So probably some library was overriding the write external storage permissions. 
I added this to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it started working
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>`

**Emphasis on the tools:node="replace" **

Answer (score 0):

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is categorized as a "dangerous" permission and need to be requested during runtime. Declaring it in the manifest file is not enough. See the document [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html).

Comment: I am doing this on a API < 23 device so no runtime permissions

Comment: @AmeyaB Go into adb shell, and try `ls -l` to check the permission of this file. Maybe it's the file permission in your way.

Comment: I dont see the file on the device after doing the adb shell and list. I dont think the file is even created. It fails when trying to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if (!BaseActivity.hasPermissions(getContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS, 12300);
    }
```

you need to enable runtime permission, run this code in onCreate.

Comment: So i am doing this on a API < 23 device so no runtime permissions

Comment: oh make sense, did you initially tried the manifest? that is  the only place it can be added other than run time.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yep have the permission in the AndroidManifest file too.